# git clone doesn't bring all filles+ have got some errors and a warning

Tags: git, github-actions

hope you are doing well, I am new to git and have been following a "Complete guide to Git" course on udemy. The problem I have is that I want to clone a repository of github to a directory on my pc and when I do so,

- I get errors like:
  invalid path '#/():;#?!'
  , then this one : fatal :  unable to checkout working tree
- I get a warning that says: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.

then I get a message that says:
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

the command I entered is : git clone https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world.git
, and the feeback was:

```
Cloning into 'hello-world'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 6554, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (909/909), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (486/486), done.
Receiremote: Total 6554 (delta 505), reused 727 (delta 375), pack-reused 5645
Receiving objects: 100% (6554/6554), 2.93 MiB | 2.12 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3275/3275), done.
error: invalid path '#/():;#?!'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

if anyone knows how to correct these errors, feel free to give me suggestions and tips, (any suggestion is welcomed).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+invalid+path+fatal%3A+unable+to+checkout+working+tree+warning%3A+Clone+succeeded%2C+but+checkout+failed

Comment: There're far too many forbidden characters in file names in the repository, especially in https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world/tree/master/%23 . The repo is not suitable to be cloned on w64.

Answer (score 0):

The repository contains some strange file names. It looks like your OS (Windows?) does not like those file names. So, you cannot check out those particular files.

The repository was still cloned. You can follow the instructions that were given to see what you have and what you are missing. In particular, you could still check out the file files that have "good" names.